# INDIRECT function not returning array

Tags: excel-formula

Thank you in advance for your time and your help.

I am using the AVERAGE and FORECAST.ETS functions on account balances to forecast them in Excel. Both of these functions require that I enter different ranges as arguments (e.g., the range of values to average for AVERAGE, and ranges for the "values" and "timeline" arguments of FORECAST.ETS).

The addresses of the ranges I am using will change with the number of periods I am averaging or using to forecast, so I am using the INDIRECT function to piece together the correct range addresses and get the arrays of values for use in the functions.

The problem I am having is that, while the INDIRECT functions I am using are referencing the correct ranges (and the cells in these ranges all contain numeric values), the INDIRECT functions are only returning the first cell's value within each range. Both the AVERAGE and FORECAST.ETS functions are returning #VALUE!

Here's what I'm working with:

When I highlight this portion of my AVERAGE function...

Original avg. function

[image]

...the ToolTip says {"E133:J133"}, which is the range I want to reference, shown here:

Range to reference

[image]

But when I highlight the entire INDIRECT function, the ToolTip shows just the first value of the range {1578.95} as opposed to something like {1578.95,5365.32,13089.65,921.63,-324.24,-4215.14}

And I am having the same problem with INDIRECT ranges in the FORECAST.ETS function.

My first guess at what the problem is is that it has something to do with the rounded brackets ("{}") that appear in the ToolTips. I tried doing the same AVERAGE function above in a blank workbook and with a simpler address for INDIRECT to reference. When I highlight this portion of the new function...

Test avg. function

[image]

…the ToolTip returns "E133:J133", which is different from when I highlighted my first function in that there are no rounded brackets enclosing the address. I think this is the problem but it is just an idea.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Please do not post formula/code as pictures.